# Add a context menu option to convert .md to html

Tags: windows, windows-registry, context-menu

I'm trying to create a context menu option that takes in a markdown file and outputs the file converted to html. I'm able to use python's markdown module to convert the file, but am having trouble getting the converted file to be written into a new file.

This is what I have so far. It works from the cmd prompt, and everything is working in the context menu except redirecting the output to `%1.html`.

```
py -m markdown -x extra "%1" > "%1.html"
```

The command is written to the following key.
`Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.md\shell\To HTML\command`

What do I need to do to make this work from a context menu option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirection is a feature of the Cmd shell, which is not being used in this situation.

You can either explicitly invoke Cmd using `cmd /c python...` (or do a similar thing with PowerShell), or write and call a custom Python script which imports the markdown module and directly writes the converted result to a file without needing to use external redirection.